# A value over size of integer

Tags: java

I'm a Vietnamese so my English's not good, please sympathize me. Thanks in advance.
I have a question.
I input a integer value but if it would been out of the size of int. 
Ex: I input a = 1323544875154846543513521
So how to catch the error?
I must input in and then check the value?

Answer (score 0):

Simple: don't use `int`, use Use `BigInteger`.

You might also wanna look other JVM languages that have number auto-casting, that is, automatically changing the number type according to the value at runtime (e.g. Clojure).

Answer (score 0):

> I input a integer value but if it would been out of the size of int.
>   Ex: I input a = 1323544875154846543513521 So how to catch the error?

```
System.out.println(Integer.MAX_VALUE+1); // anymore than the max will wrap around, value printed = -2147483648
System.out.println(Integer.MIN_VALUE-1); // if less than the min it will also wrap around, value printed = 2147483647
```

you could use [**`Math.toIntExact(long value)`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#toIntExact-long-) if you want to receive an exception on overflow/underflow.

Alternatively, you could use [**`BigInteger`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) or [**`BigDecimal`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) which have no limit in size (your RAM is the limit).